Output from function morphing parent object
I am working on a Nuxt3, Vue3, Laravel project.
In one of my components, I have this watcher:
watch(() => props.subConfig, (newSubConfig) => {
    if (newSubConfig.type !== type.value?.id) {
        type.value = TYPE_LIST.find(type => type.id === newSubConfig.type);
    }

    if (newSubConfig.trial_months !== trialMonths.value?.id) {
        trialMonths.value = TRIAL_MONTHS_LIST.find(item => item.id === newSubConfig.trial_months);
    }

    console.log(delegatedSubConfig.value);

    if (!isEqual(newSubConfig, delegatedSubConfig.value)) {
        delegatedSubConfig.value = {
            uuid: props.userUuid,
            tiers: mapTiers(newSubConfig.sell_price_config, newSubConfig.buy_margin_config),
            trial_months: newSubConfig.trial_months,
            type: newSubConfig.type,
            product: newSubConfig.product,
        };

        console.log(delegatedSubConfig.value);
    }
}, { immediate: true, deep: true });

The mapTiers function (in the same component) is:
const mapTiers = (sellPriceConfig: Array<object>, buyMarginConfig: Array<object>) => {

    const tiers = sellPriceConfig.map((item, index) => ({
        up_to: item.up_to,
        buy_margin: (buyMarginConfig?.[index]?.buy_margin ?? 0) * 100,
        unit_amount: item.unit_amount / 100,
        flat_amount: item.flat_amount / 100,
    }));

    console.log('tiers => ', tiers);

    return tiers;
};

The console.log('tiers => ', tiers); shows:
[
{up_to: 1, buy_margin: 0, unit_amount: 15, flat_amount: 10}
{up_to: 10, buy_margin: 0, unit_amount: 20, flat_amount: 10}
{up_to: 20, buy_margin: 0, unit_amount: 30, flat_amount: 10}
...
{up_to: 'inf', buy_margin: 0, unit_amount: 310, flat_amount: 10}
]

The first console.log(delegatedSubConfig.value); (from the watch) shows:
undefined

The second console.log(delegatedSubConfig.value); (from the watch) shows:
{
  "uuid": "ed82ccfa-f5b6-4e88-8c3d-7de72a6d6da9",
  "tiers": [
    {
      "up_to": 1,
      "buy_margin": 0,
      "unit_amount": 15,
      "flat_amount": 10
    },
    {
      "up_to": 10,
      "buy_margin": 0,
      "unit_amount": 20,
      "flat_amount": 10
    },
      ...,
    {
      "up_to": 290,
      "buy_margin": 0,
      "unit_amount": 300,
      "flat_amount": 10
    },
    {
      "up_to": "inf",
      "buy_margin": 0,
      "unit_amount": 310,
      "flat_amount": 10
    }
  ],
  "trial_months": 1,
  "type": "volume",
  "product": "properties",
  "number_3": 1,
  "number_4": 10,
  "number_5": 15,
  "number_6": 0,
  "number_9": 10,
  "number_10": 10,
  "number_11": 20,
  "number_12": 0,
   ...,
  "number_171": 280,
  "number_172": 10,
  "number_173": 290,
  "number_174": 0,
  "number_177": 290,
  "number_178": 10,
  "number_179": 300,
  "number_180": 0,
  "number_182": 10,
  "number_183": 310,
  "number_184": 0
}

If I return an empty array from mapTiers function the The second console.log(delegatedSubConfig.value); (from the watch) shows:
{
  "uuid": "ed82ccfa-f5b6-4e88-8c3d-7de72a6d6da9",
  "tiers": [],
  "trial_months": 1,
  "type": "volume",
  "product": "properties"
}

The mapTiers seems to be adding the "number_xx" keys (which are a match to the tiers values). What is adding these keys?

there's nothing in the code that adds number_xx, check elsewhere
